# how to display database values in form of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to display two database values in this way

```
array(
array(0.05, 0.95),
array(0.1, 0.9),
array(0.2, 0.8),
array(0.25, 0.75),
array(0.45, 0.55),
array(0.5, 0.5),
array(0.55, 0.45),
array(0.85, 0.15),
array(0.9, 0.1),
array(0.95, 0.05)
 );
```

but i am having the data below

```
array(76.8736, 1, 76.8736, 3, 869.69500946137, 2, 869.69500946137, 5, 431, 6, 23.55, 2, 869.69500946137, 3, 869.69500946137, 1, 869.69500946137, 30, 567, 36, 33, 45, 456, 15, 562, 3, 441, 17)
```

my codes is below

```
<?php

 include 'linker.php';


 $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM android_data");
 $statement->execute();
 $array1 = [];

 foreach( $statement -> get_result() as $row ){

     array_push($array1, $row['distance']);
     array_push($array1, $row['speed']);
 }
  $arr ='array('.implode(', ',$array1).')';

    echo $arr; 
 ?>
```

please how can anybody help me. Thanks

Comment: you both data is in different ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pushing all the values directly into the main array, you should create a new array with the values and push that into the main array:

```
foreach( $statement -> get_result() as $row ){
    $array1[] = [
        $row['distance'],
        $row['speed']
    ];
}
```